# Desktop Duplication API - DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO.LastPresentTime is 0 for the first 5 minutes after I restart my computer

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, screen-capture, desktop-duplication

I use Desktop Duplication API to take screenshots of the desktop. It works fine, except the first 5 minutes after I restart my computer. In these first 5 minutes `lFrameInfo.LastPresentTime.HighPart` is always 0, so the CaptureScreen() function exits without taking a screenshot. If I take out the if with the `lFrameInfo.LastPresentTime.HighPart == 0` check, then the code works, but it takes a screenshot at every mouse movement, even if the screen does not changed.

According to the documentation for LastPresentTime: "*a zero value indicates that the desktop image was not updated since an application last called the IDXGIOutputDuplication::AcquireNextFrame method to acquire the next frame of the desktop image.*" But this is not true for me, even if I watch a 60fps youtube video, LastPresentTime is 0 for the first 5 minutes after a computer restart.

My system: Win10 x64, 13900k, RTX 4700

Here is the code:

```
bool DXGIScreenCapture::CaptureScreen()
{
    HRESULT hr(E_FAIL);
    IDXGIResource* lDesktopResource = nullptr;
    DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO lFrameInfo;

    hr = _lDeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(500, &lFrameInfo, &lDesktopResource);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    if (lFrameInfo.LastPresentTime.HighPart == 0) // not interested in just mouse updates, which can happen much faster than 60fps if you really shake the mouse
    {
        hr = _lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
        return false;
    }

    // QI for ID3D11Texture2D
    hr = lDesktopResource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&_lAcquiredDesktopImage));
    lDesktopResource->Release();
    lDesktopResource = nullptr;
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        hr = _lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();
        return false;
    }

    _lImmediateContext->CopyResource(currTexture, _lAcquiredDesktopImage);
    UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
    _lImmediateContext->Map(currTexture, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &_resource);
    _lImmediateContext->Unmap(currTexture, 0);
    hr = _lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Desktop Duplication API doesn't capture screenshot, it's not a "screenshot api", it's a duplication api, it's capable of duplicating the screen (and putting it in like a mailbox). So indeed, when nothing changes, nothing is put in the mailbox. First thing to do is test the official sample https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DXGIDesktopDuplication if it works then you code has a problem. I would just remove your `LastPresentTime.HighPart` test which seems wrong, you must test the whole quad, or just don't test anyway.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Using QuadPart instead of HighPart solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/ns-dxgi1_2-dxgi_outdupl_frame_info) structure,

> The operating system calls the [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) function to
> obtain the value.

And according to [Acquiring high-resolution time stamps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps#resolution-precision-accuracy-and-stability),

> [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter) reads the performance counter and returns **the
> total number of ticks** that have occurred **since the Windows operating
> system was started**, including the time when the machine was in a sleep
> state such as standby, hibernate, or connected standby.

So, it's correct that the `HighPart` of the ticks is `0` since the Windows operating system was started. To use the [LARGE_INTEGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-large_integer-r1) union,

> If your compiler has built-in support for 64-bit integers, use the
> **QuadPart** member to store the 64-bit integer. Otherwise, use the
> **LowPart and HighPart** members to store the 64-bit integer.